# Prove that $1-x^n \le \dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}$ if $0<x<1$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Hy guys. I'm trying to prove this inequality for any $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$

$$1- x^n \le \dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{x^k}$$

Where $0<x<1$.

My solution attempt was to use induction over $k$

For case $k=1$, we have to prove that

$$1- x^n \le \dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}$$

I thought that maybe an induction on $ n $ would solve it now, but I wondered if there was another way less laborious. Can someone help me?

Comment: $1/x < 1/x^k$ for $0 < x < 1$, therefore it suffices to prove the inequality for $k=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define for $0<x<1$,
$$f(x)=x^k-x^{n+k}$$
Then
$$f'(x)=kx^{k-1}-(n+k)x^{n+k-1}$$
Now let's find the zeros of $f'$. Putting $f'(x)=0$ and dividing by $x^{k-1}$ we get
$$k=(n+k)x^n$$
Now $f(x)\to 0$ when $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to1^-$. Furthermore, $f(x)>0$, so at $x_0^n=\dfrac k{n+k}$, $f$ meets its maximum.
Now, for $0<x<1$,
$$x^k(1-x^n)=f(x)\le f(x_0)=x_0^k\left(1-\frac{k}{n+k}\right)=x_0^k\frac{n}{n+k}<\frac n{n+1}$$
and your inequality follows.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

WTS $  x ( 1  - x^n) \leq \frac{n}{n+1} $

We will show something stronger, namely $ x (  1 - x^n ) \leq \frac{ n } { (n+1) \sqrt[n] {n+1}}$.

This follows by applying weighted AM-GM:

$$ \frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{ (nx^n) \times 1 + ( 1 - x^n) \times n } { n+1} \geq \sqrt[n+1] {nx^n ( 1-x^n)^n}.$$

So $ x ( 1 - x^n) \leq \sqrt[n]{\frac{n^{n+1} } { n(n+1)^{n+1}} }= \frac{n}{(n+1) \sqrt[n]{n+1}}.$

Equality holds when $nx^n = 1 - x^n \Rightarrow  x = \frac{ 1 } { \sqrt[n] { n+1} } $.

---

Note: The inequality $ x^k ( 1 - x^n) \leq \frac{n}{n+1}$ can also be done in a similar manner. Try it!